# Predefined definitions in Xtext script

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I have the following Xtext grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    defines+=Define*
    usages+=Usage*
;

Define:
    'define' name=ID
;

Usage:
    'usage' name=[Define]
;
```

And user's my.mydsl works well:

```
define first

usage first
```

Now, I would like to separate definitions from usage. Specifically, the requirement is to put one set of definitions into file called ‘defs1.mydsl’ and another set of (different) definitions into file called ‘defs2.mydsl’. The intention is to provide them as read only definitions and make them be a part of Eclipse Xtext plugin.

A user editable file would contain ‘use’ and ‘usage’ directives only:

```
use "defs2.mydsl"

usage second
```

Would you please describe the steps I should follow to implement this?

Additional question – may I limit user to use ‘use’ and ‘usage’ directives only?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the use directive a must requirement. If you leave it out it will work out of the box if you put a jar containing the defs.mydsl to the class path of the project containing the use.mydsl. If not the term to search for is importUri based scoping (not recommended) if you want to even omit the putting on the class path it will be even more pain (ProjectStateHelper / ToBeBuiltContribution)

Comment: Yes, 'use' directive is a must. It supposed to select between different sets of 'define's. Are you aware about existence of good example for importUri usage?

Comment: No at least no for the new xtext 29 style workflow.

Comment: You could try to avoid import uri when adapting iqualifiednameprovider to return file.mydsl.name as qualified name (using the eibject resources uri) and turn use file.mydsl. Into a wildcard import file.mydsl.*

Comment: Hi Christian, I am new for Xtext and I am not sure I follow the proposal. Would it be possible to describe the steps or point me an example I can refer to? Please note, the user's project is not Java, but CDT, so, it does not define classpath by its own.

Comment: Sry that would be too time consuming to digg into that and develop a prototype (I have nothing ready) - but what about having 2 user projects - one for c stuff and one for the model

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question was answered by [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935687/christian-dietrich)  at [Eclipse Community Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1078908/)